# Ghost Multipolygons block Overlay Intersection

Tags: polygon, intersection, geopandas

I'm really desapointed, because I did everything to avoid Multipolygon in my script but last treatment blocks because of Multipolygon :

`File "/.../Zonage/Zonage_standalone.py", line 254, in zonage
    zonage = gpd.overlay(clip, parc, how='intersection') # Intersection parcellaire et zonage`

`AttributeError: 'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'exterior'`

You can find my script and datas [here](https://we.tl/Ka82Xy3xLN) if you want to help me.

Comment: You can convert the MultiPolygon to a Polygon? (or split them over multiple rows?)

Comment: I create a fonction to explode multipolygons. I tested my script with some datas and it worked well. But with these datas Multipolygons come back... :/

Comment: There is a `explode` method on GeoSeries/GeoDataFrame that can do that as well. You will need to be clearer with what you mean with "ghost" multipolygons.

Comment: Oh ! I didn't find this method before :/ I will try it now. "Ghost multipolygons" means that one or both of gdf used in intersection may contain multipolygons but before intersection I used 2 tricks (my explode fonction for both, and geometry to str wkt,  groupby str wkt, str wkt to geometry) to delete them. When i tried to highlight multipolygons, it didn't work `for i, row in parc.iterrows(): typeparc = parc.geom_type[i]
        print(typeparc)
        if typeparc != 'Polygon':
            print('parc',typeparc)`

Answer (score 3):

The `geopandas.overlay` function indeed does not work on MultiPolygons.

But, you can use the `explode` method to ensure that your dataframe does not contain any MultiPolygons. The `explode` method will convert any row with a MultiPolygon geometry into multiple rows with the different Polygons. Currently this only 'explodes' the geometry column, so if you want to retain the other columns (and repeating the values for exploded rows), you need to merge the result with the original frame (assuming `df` is a GeoDataFrame with MultiPolygons):

```
geoms_exploded = df.explode().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
df_new = df.drop(columns='geometry').join(geoms_exploded.rename('geometry'))
df_new = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df_new)
```

but I opened an issue for an enhancement request to let `explode` also work on GeoDataFrames out of the box: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/667

Comment: I exploded the 2 gdf before overlay and I still have the error...

Comment: Then please show the code (you can add it to the original question)